# Crear pop up con ayuda bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap, popup

Estoy creando una ventana emergente tipo "pop up" (como si fuera un confirm() pero quiero que en vez de tenga los botones típicos Aceptar-Cancelar, tenga los valores: Boton1 - Boton2, y cada uno haga X código...

Tengo el siguiente código en el index.php:

```
echo "<td onclick='cambiar_estado(this);' width=\"08%\" id=\"".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."\">" ?>
    <!-- Columna ESTADO del usuario. -->
        <center>
         <?php
            $estado = 1;
            echo "<a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal_cambiar_estado' data-id='\"".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."\">' class='cambiar_estado' onclick='cambiar_estado(this);'>";
                echo "<img src=\"/imagenes/".$row['estado'].".gif\">";
            echo "</a>";
         ?>
        </center>
  <?php 
echo "</td>";
```

Ahora lo que quiero es una función para que cargue los botones 1-2, ¿dichos botons los tengo que crear en Javascript? O podría hacer la creación a la vez que creo el pop up con el siguiente código:

```
<button type="button1" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#boton1">Boton1</button>
```

Lo mismo para el boton2.

Comment: Si creas un `modal` de bootstrap para simular un pop-up de confirmación, puedes crear los botones que quieras, y añadirles una función para cada uno de ellos

Comment: sumandome a @Cheshire http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ aqui puedes ver un poco mas

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo? Googleando vi que la mayoría crea los botones con Ajax.

Comment: @omaza1990 Si ese pop-up va a ser siempre así, no necesitas ajax. Ajax lo usarás únicamente para enviar datos a un servidor y mostrarlos en un contenedor de tu web (sin necesidad de refrescar)

Comment: Ya conseguí como añadir los botones, mil gracias. Encontré un ejemplo parecido gracias al link de @sioesi

Comment: El problema, y grave, viene ahora: tenemos 3 estados (0-1-2). Por cada estado preguntamos al pulsar en el enlace si queremos cambiar el estado a boton1 o boton2 (siendo estado=0), o a boton0 o boton2 (siendo estado=1) o a boton0 o boton1 (siendo estado=2). Espero explicarme. Tengo una consulta donde recojo los estados actuales del usuario/enlace a clickear,... ¿necesito tantos ifs como sean necesarios para los estados(en este caso, if(row.id==1) opciones (boton0, boton2? No sé si me explico.

Comment: @omaza1990 crea otra pregunta, explicando tu contexto, tu codigo, que llevas hecho y que quieres conseguir

Comment: no me deja publicar, solo cada 40 minutos. ¿Edito?

Answer (score 1):

Entonces mas que tener el problema de invocar el modal de bootstrap desde php, creo que es usar acciones personalizadas dentro del modal.

Para eso puedes usar la libreria [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/getting-started.html)

Aqui hay un ejemplo usando cuatro botones, que lo colocamos dentro del elemento `buttons` y en el `callback` de cada uno de ellos podemos programar lo que queramos

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
         mostrar();
     });

function mostrar(){
    bootbox.dialog({
        message: 'Algún mensaje de ayuda',
        title: "Título",
        keyboard  : true,
        buttons: {
            opUno: {
                label: " Cosa 1",
                className: "btn purple fa fa-calendar",
                callback: function() {
                    alert("Opción 1")
                }
            },
            opDos: {
                label: " Cosa 2",
                className: "btn green fa fa-briefcase",
                callback: function() {
                    alert("Opción 2")
                }
            },
            opTres: {
                label: " Cosa 3",
                className: "btn red fa fa-ban",
                callback: function() {
                    alert("Opción 3")
                }
            },
            opCuatro : {
                label: " Cosa 4",
                className: "btn blue fa fa-edit",
                callback: function() {
                    alert("Opción 4")
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://bootboxjs.com/bootbox.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button id="btn">Abrir modal</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me da la sensación de que te estás complicando mucho. Por matizar, ¿no sería más fácil programarlo en PHP sobre HTML y no al revés?

```html
<?php ?>
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
      if (true) {
    ?>
    
    <p>Este texto se verá si cumple la condición anterior</p>
    
    <?php
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Te recomendaría crear un modal o popup en un `index.php` empezando el documento con `<?php ?>` y una vez funcione cambia mediante PHP el cuerpo HTML.

Comment: esto parece ser una recomendación y no una respuesta

Comment: Junto con el enlace que le adjuntas debería aclararse el sólo. Siguiendo los ejemplos de Bootstrap la mayor complicación que tiene es aunarlo en un PHP. A mi parecer es más engorroso programar el cuerpo en PHP.